# rxjava and clojure asynchrony mystery: futures promises and agents, oh my

Tags: clojure, reactive-programming, netflix, rx-java

I apologize in advance for the length of this note. I spent considerable time making it shorter, and this was as small as I could get it.

I have a mystery and would be grateful for your help. This mystery comes from the behavior of an rxjava `observer` I wrote in Clojure over a couple of straightforward `observable`s cribbed from online samples.

One observable synchronously sends messages to the `onNext` handlers of its observers, and my supposedly principled observer behaves as expected.

The other observable asynchronously does the same, on another thread, via a Clojure `future`. The exact same observer does not capture all events posted to its `onNext`; it just seems to lose a random number of messages at the tail.

There is an intentional race in the following between the expiration of a wait for the `promise`d `onCompleted` and the expiration of a wait for all events sent to an `agent` collector. If the `promise` wins, I expect to see `false` for `onCompleted` and a possibly short queue in the `agent`. If the `agent` wins, I expect to see `true` for `onCompleted` and all messages from the `agent`'s queue. The one result I DO NOT expect is `true` for `onCompleted` AND a short queue from the `agent`. But, Murphy doesn't sleep, and that's exactly what I see. I don't know whether garbage-collection is at fault, or some internal queuing to Clojure's STM, or my stupidity, or something else altogether.

I present the source in the order of its self-contained form, here, so that it can be run directly via `lein repl`.  There are three cermonials to get out of the way: first, the leiningen project file, `project.clj`, which declares dependency on the `0.9.0` version of Netflix's rxjava:

```
(defproject expt2 "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure               "1.5.1"]
                 [com.netflix.rxjava/rxjava-clojure "0.9.0"]]
  :main expt2.core)
```

Now, the namespace and a Clojure requirement and the Java imports:

```
(ns expt2.core
  (:require clojure.pprint)
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [distinct])
  (:import [rx Observable subscriptions.Subscriptions]))
```

Finally, a macro for output to the console:

```
(defmacro pdump [x]
  `(let [x# ~x]
     (do (println "----------------")
         (clojure.pprint/pprint '~x)
         (println "~~>")
         (clojure.pprint/pprint x#)
         (println "----------------")
         x#)))
```

Finally, to my observer. I use an `agent` to collect the messages sent by any observable's `onNext`. I use an `atom` to collect a potential `onError`. I use a `promise` for the `onCompleted` so that consumers external to the observer can wait on it.

```
(defn- subscribe-collectors [obl]
  (let [;; Keep a sequence of all values sent:
        onNextCollector      (agent [])
        ;; Only need one value if the observable errors out:
        onErrorCollector     (atom nil)
        ;; Use a promise for 'completed' so we can wait for it on
        ;; another thread:
        onCompletedCollector (promise)]
    (letfn [;; When observable sends a value, relay it to our agent"
            (collect-next      [item] (send onNextCollector (fn [state] (conj state item))))
            ;; If observable errors out, just set our exception;
            (collect-error     [excp] (reset!  onErrorCollector     excp))
            ;; When observable completes, deliver on the promise:
            (collect-completed [    ] (deliver onCompletedCollector true))
            ;; In all cases, report out the back end with this:
            (report-collectors [    ]
              (pdump
               ;; Wait for everything that has been sent to the agent
               ;; to drain (presumably internal message queues):
               {:onNext      (do (await-for 1000 onNextCollector)
                                 ;; Then produce the results:
                                 @onNextCollector)
                ;; If we ever saw an error, here it is:
                :onError     @onErrorCollector
                ;; Wait at most 1 second for the promise to complete;
                ;; if it does not complete, then produce 'false'.
                ;; I expect if this times out before the agent
                ;; times out to see an 'onCompleted' of 'false'.
                :onCompleted (deref onCompletedCollector 1000 false)
                }))]
      ;; Recognize that the observable 'obl' may run on another thread:
      (-> obl
          (.subscribe collect-next collect-error collect-completed))
      ;; Therefore, produce results that wait, with timeouts, on both
      ;; the completion event and on the draining of the (presumed)
      ;; message queue to the agent.
      (report-collectors))))
```

Now, here is a synchronous observable. It pumps 25 messages down the `onNext` throats of its observers, then calls their `onCompleted`s.

```
(defn- customObservableBlocking []
  (Observable/create
    (fn [observer]                       ; This is the 'subscribe' method.
      ;; Send 25 strings to the observer's onNext:
      (doseq [x (range 25)]
        (-> observer (.onNext (str "SynchedValue_" x))))
      ; After sending all values, complete the sequence:
      (-> observer .onCompleted)
      ; return a NoOpSubsription since this blocks and thus
      ; can't be unsubscribed (disposed):
      (Subscriptions/empty))))
```

We subscribe our observer to this observable:

```
;;; The value of the following is the list of all 25 events:
(-> (customObservableBlocking)
    (subscribe-collectors))
```

It works as expected, and we see the following results on the console

```
{:onNext (do (await-for 1000 onNextCollector) @onNextCollector),
 :onError @onErrorCollector,
 :onCompleted (deref onCompletedCollector 1000 false)}
~~>
{:onNext
 ["SynchedValue_0"
  "SynchedValue_1"
  "SynchedValue_2"
  "SynchedValue_3"
  "SynchedValue_4"
  "SynchedValue_5"
  "SynchedValue_6"
  "SynchedValue_7"
  "SynchedValue_8"
  "SynchedValue_9"
  "SynchedValue_10"
  "SynchedValue_11"
  "SynchedValue_12"
  "SynchedValue_13"
  "SynchedValue_14"
  "SynchedValue_15"
  "SynchedValue_16"
  "SynchedValue_17"
  "SynchedValue_18"
  "SynchedValue_19"
  "SynchedValue_20"
  "SynchedValue_21"
  "SynchedValue_22"
  "SynchedValue_23"
  "SynchedValue_24"],
 :onError nil,
 :onCompleted true}
----------------
```

Here is an asynchronous observable that does exactly the same thing, only on a `future`'s thread:

```
(defn- customObservableNonBlocking []
  (Observable/create
    (fn [observer]                       ; This is the 'subscribe' method
      (let [f (future
                ;; On another thread, send 25 strings:
                (doseq [x (range 25)]
                  (-> observer (.onNext (str "AsynchValue_" x))))
                ; After sending all values, complete the sequence:
                (-> observer .onCompleted))]
        ; Return a disposable (unsubscribe) that cancels the future:
        (Subscriptions/create #(future-cancel f))))))

;;; For unknown reasons, the following does not produce all 25 events:
(-> (customObservableNonBlocking)
    (subscribe-collectors))
```

But, surprise, here is what we see on the console: `true` for `onCompleted`, implying that the `promise` DID NOT TIME-OUT; but only some of the asynch messages.  The actual number of messages we see varies from run to run, implying that there is some concurrency phenomenon at play. Clues appreciated.

```
----------------
{:onNext (do (await-for 1000 onNextCollector) @onNextCollector),
 :onError @onErrorCollector,
 :onCompleted (deref onCompletedCollector 1000 false)}
~~>
{:onNext
 ["AsynchValue_0"
  "AsynchValue_1"
  "AsynchValue_2"
  "AsynchValue_3"
  "AsynchValue_4"
  "AsynchValue_5"
  "AsynchValue_6"],
 :onError nil,
 :onCompleted true}
----------------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `await-for` on agent means **Blocks the current thread until all actions *dispatched thus
far* (from this thread or agent) to the agents have occurred**, which means that it may happen that after your await is over there is still some other thread that can send messages to the agent and that is what is happening in your case. After your await on agent is over and you have deref its value in the `:onNext` key in the map, then you wait for the on completed promise which turns out to be true after the wait but in the mean time some other messages were dispatched to the agent to be collected into the vector.

You can solve this by having the `:onCompleted` key as the first key in the map which basically means wait for the completion and then wait for the agents coz by that time there is no more `send` calls on the agent can happen after as have already received onCompleted.

```
{:onCompleted (deref onCompletedCollector 1000 false)
 :onNext      (do (await-for 0 onNextCollector)
                                 @onNextCollector)
 :onError     @onErrorCollector
 }
```